# Неправильное смещение элементов при удалении

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть 6 блоков c float:left, в каждом блоке чекбокс, при нажатии на который через секунду этот блок удаляется, и когда все блоки выбраны - появляется надпись.Блоки при удалении должны смещаться справа налево снизу вверх  без пустых мест.Но при удалении верхних блоков нижние съезжают.Прошу помоши с решением этой проблемы.

в состоянии покоя:
[image: в состоянии покоя]

После удаления первого блока:
[image: После удаления первого блока]

```js
function removeElementsByClass(className){
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
      while(elements.length > 0){
          elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
      }
    }
    var counter = 0;
    function check(f) {
      var parent = f.parentNode;
      for (var i = 0; i < parent.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (parent.childNodes[i].className == "checkboxholder") {
      toCheck = parent.childNodes[i];
      break;
    }
}
        if (toCheck.checked == false) {
          var checkboxinner = f.innerHTML,
          height = parent.offsetHeight,
          label = parent.lastElementChild;
          marginTop = (height - 95) * -1;
          f.setAttribute("id", "checkbox_active");
          f.outerHTML += '<div class="overlay" style="height:'+height+'px;margin-top:'+marginTop+'px;"></div>';
          for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            var coursestest = document.getElementsByClassName('course');
            if (coursestest[i] == parent) {
              counter += 1;
              setTimeout(function(){parent.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");}, 1000);
            }
          }
      } else {
          counter -= 1;
        }
      var courses = document.getElementById('courses');
      if (counter == 6) {
        courses.innerHTML = '<h2><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>Задание выполнено</h2>';
      }
    }
```

```css
.courses_list{
   margin-top: 50px;
   float: left;
   min-height: 1300px;
   width: 960px;
  }
  .course{
   float: left;
   width: 300px;
   margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.38);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.38);
   box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.38);
  }
   .thumbnail{
    height: 174px;
   }
   .course:hover>.thumbnail{
    border-bottom: 4px solid #8cc34b;
    transition: .05s ease;
   }
   .course:hover>h2{
    color: #8cc34b;
    transition: .1s ease;
   }
   .course:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
   }
   .course>h2,.course>p,.course>span{
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
   }
   .course>h2{
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 600;
   }
   .course>p{
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 10px;
   }
   .course>span{
    float: left;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    opacity: .7;
   }
   .course>span>i{
    padding-right: 8px;
   }
   .course:hover>h2{
    color: #8cc34b;
    transition: .1s ease;
   }
    .checkbox{
     width: 100%;
     float: left;
     margin-top: 16px;
     height: 25px;
     font-size: 18px;
     margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    .checkbox>i{
     margin-right: 8px;
     line-height: 25px;
    }
    input[type=checkbox] { display:none;}
    input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      display: box;
    }
    input[type=checkbox] + label{cursor: pointer;z-index: 99;padding-left: 20px;}
    input[type=checkbox] + label:before { content: "\f096";transition: .5s ease;}
    input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before { content: "\f046"; }
    input[type=checkbox] + label:before { letter-spacing: 10px; }
    input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{color: #8cc34b}
    #checkbox_active,#checkbox_active:before{
     content: "\f046";
     color: #8cc34b;
    }
    .overlay{
     background: #8cc34b;
     opacity: .2;
     width: 300px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="courses_list">
          <div class="course">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="img/js.png" alt=""></div>
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni tempore nobis atque ipsam ipsum placeat, ex, officiis nihil.</p>
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxholder"  autocomplete="off" id="checkbox1"/><label for="checkbox1" onclick="check(this);" class="checkbox">Посмотрел</label>
          </div>
            <div class="course even">
              <div class="thumbnail"><img src="img/jq.png" alt=""></div>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum.</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis sit totam unde ab ullam, earum est laboriosam nobis.</p>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxholder"  autocomplete="off" id="checkbox2"/><label for="checkbox2" onclick="check(this);" class="checkbox">Посмотрел</label>
            </div>
            <div class="course">
              <div class="thumbnail"><img src="img/base.png" alt=""></div>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem neque accusamus rem culpa temporibus atque saepe aperiam officia explicabo error.</p>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxholder"  autocomplete="off" id="checkbox3"/><label for="checkbox3" onclick="check(this);" class="checkbox">Посмотрел</label>
            </div>
            <div style="height: 20px;"></div>
            <div class="course">
              <div class="thumbnail"><img src="img/adapt.png" alt=""></div>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea, sunt.</p>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxholder"  autocomplete="off" id="checkbox4"/><label for="checkbox4" onclick="check(this);" class="checkbox">Посмотрел</label>
            </div>
          <div class="course even">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="img/btn.png" alt=""></div>
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex saepe, voluptas qui itaque sapiente eius. Quisquam dolores magni suscipit, perferendis commodi quidem ipsum corrupti eum.</p>
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxholder"  autocomplete="off" id="checkbox5"/><label for="checkbox5" onclick="check(this);" class="checkbox">Посмотрел</label>
          </div>
          <div class="course">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="img/css.png" alt=""></div>
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum, minima.</p>
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxholder"  autocomplete="off" id="checkbox6"/><label for="checkbox6" onclick="check(this);" class="checkbox">Посмотрел</label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Не хотите ли воспользоваться [этой библиотекой](http://masonry.desandro.com/)? Судя по всему, блоки у вас могут быть различной высоты, так что она бы отлично подошла.

Comment: Спасибо, но желательно решить это без использjвания сторонних библиотек.

Comment: Это поисходит из-за специфичности свойства `float`, так как блоки различной высоты. Попробуйте сделать их не через `float`, а через `inline-block`, но не забывайте про размер шрифта у родителя и свойство `vertical-align`, которое необходимо выставить в значение `top`

Comment: @Surfin Bird, можно в двух словах что делает эта библиотека?

Comment: @pepel_xD, выводит блоки разной высоты столбцами, как указано на страничке и в примерах. Есть анимация и встроенная работа с ресайзом. Где-то есть и другая библиотека, но попроще и без анимаций.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример возможной реализации. Обратите внимание на измененные правила в классах `.courses_list` и `.course`, а так же на удаленную прослойку в виде пустого `<div style="height: 20px;"></div>` из разметки страницы.

```js
function removeElementsByClass(className){
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
      while(elements.length > 0){
          elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
      }
    }
    var counter = 0;
    function check(f) {
      var parent = f.parentNode;
      for (var i = 0; i < parent.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (parent.childNodes[i].className == "checkboxholder") {
      toCheck = parent.childNodes[i];
      break;
    }
}
        if (toCheck.checked == false) {
          var checkboxinner = f.innerHTML,
          height = parent.offsetHeight,
          label = parent.lastElementChild;
          marginTop = (height - 95) * -1;
          f.setAttribute("id", "checkbox_active");
          f.outerHTML += '<div class="overlay" style="height:'+height+'px;margin-top:'+marginTop+'px;"></div>';
          for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            var coursestest = document.getElementsByClassName('course');
            if (coursestest[i] == parent) {
              counter += 1;
              setTimeout(function(){parent.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");}, 1000);
            }
          }
      } else {
          counter -= 1;
        }
      var courses = document.getElementById('courses');
      if (counter == 6) {
        courses.innerHTML = '<h2><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>Задание выполнено</h2>';
      }
    }
```

```css
.courses_list{
   margin-top: 50px;
   float: left;
   min-height: 1300px;
   width: 960px;
            font-size: 0;
  }
  .course{
   font-size: 16px;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
   width: 300px;
   margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.38);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.38);
   box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.38);
  }
   .thumbnail{
    height: 174px;
   }
   .course:hover>.thumbnail{
    border-bottom: 4px solid #8cc34b;
    transition: .05s ease;
   }
   .course:hover>h2{
    color: #8cc34b;
    transition: .1s ease;
   }
   .course:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
   }
   .course>h2,.course>p,.course>span{
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
   }
   .course>h2{
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 600;
   }
   .course>p{
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 10px;
   }
   .course>span{
    float: left;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    opacity: .7;
   }
   .course>span>i{
    padding-right: 8px;
   }
   .course:hover>h2{
    color: #8cc34b;
    transition: .1s ease;
   }
    .checkbox{
     width: 100%;
     float: left;
     margin-top: 16px;
     height: 25px;
     font-size: 18px;
     margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    .checkbox>i{
     margin-right: 8px;
     line-height: 25px;
    }
    input[type=checkbox] { display:none;}
    input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      display: box;
    }
    input[type=checkbox] + label{cursor: pointer;z-index: 99;padding-left: 20px;}
    input[type=checkbox] + label:before { content: "\f096";transition: .5s ease;}
    input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before { content: "\f046"; }
    input[type=checkbox] + label:before { letter-spacing: 10px; }
    input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{color: #8cc34b}
    #checkbox_active,#checkbox_active:before{
     content: "\f046";
     color: #8cc34b;
    }
    .overlay{
     background: #8cc34b;
     opacity: .2;
     width: 300px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="courses_list">
          <div class="course">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="img/js.png" alt=""></div>
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni tempore nobis atque ipsam ipsum placeat, ex, officiis nihil.</p>
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxholder"  autocomplete="off" id="checkbox1"/><label for="checkbox1" onclick="check(this);" class="checkbox">Посмотрел</label>
          </div>
            <div class="course even">
              <div class="thumbnail"><img src="img/jq.png" alt=""></div>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum.</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis sit totam unde ab ullam, earum est laboriosam nobis.</p>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxholder"  autocomplete="off" id="checkbox2"/><label for="checkbox2" onclick="check(this);" class="checkbox">Посмотрел</label>
            </div>
            <div class="course">
              <div class="thumbnail"><img src="img/base.png" alt=""></div>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem neque accusamus rem culpa temporibus atque saepe aperiam officia explicabo error.</p>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxholder"  autocomplete="off" id="checkbox3"/><label for="checkbox3" onclick="check(this);" class="checkbox">Посмотрел</label>
            </div>
            <div class="course">
              <div class="thumbnail"><img src="img/adapt.png" alt=""></div>
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea, sunt.</p>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxholder"  autocomplete="off" id="checkbox4"/><label for="checkbox4" onclick="check(this);" class="checkbox">Посмотрел</label>
            </div>
          <div class="course even">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="img/btn.png" alt=""></div>
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex saepe, voluptas qui itaque sapiente eius. Quisquam dolores magni suscipit, perferendis commodi quidem ipsum corrupti eum.</p>
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxholder"  autocomplete="off" id="checkbox5"/><label for="checkbox5" onclick="check(this);" class="checkbox">Посмотрел</label>
          </div>
          <div class="course">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="img/css.png" alt=""></div>
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum, minima.</p>
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxholder"  autocomplete="off" id="checkbox6"/><label for="checkbox6" onclick="check(this);" class="checkbox">Посмотрел</label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

P.S. Рекомендую подробнее прочитать про свойство `float` и его подводные камни.

Comment: Огромное спасибо